# Hierarchy for multiple components in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, components

Regarding to this question I have a look at [Master/Detail Components](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt3) page but there is not enough information about this. In addition to that there is also another great tutorial for Angular folder hierarchy on [Angular Folder Structure](https://medium.com/@motcowley/angular-folder-structure-d1809be95542) but that is also not covering my question.

[image]

I have three components (let's call them) ComponentA, ComponentB and ComponentC and I want to merge all of them in another components called ComponentX as shown on the image. As the data is different for each of 3 components, I need to separate all of them with 3 components with the following hierarchy:

-ComponentX (folder)

```
    -ComponentA (folder)
        -componentA.html
        -componentA.ts
        -componentA.model.ts

    -ComponentB (folder)
        -componentB.html
        -componentB.ts
        -componentB.model.ts

    -ComponentC (folder)
        -componentC.html
        -componentC.ts
        -componentC.model.ts

    -componentX.html
    -componentX.ts
    -componentX.model.ts ???
```

Is this hierarchy approach is correct? On the other hand if Component X is just a panel can we use componentX.model.ts if a model data that is used for general purpose for all of 2 or 3 components (A, B and C) need to be retrieved? Which approach should I follow? And what is the best way in order to share data between two components i.e. master-detail? service or input-output approach? Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

I'm telling you how I would have done it, but that's subjective, so consider using this if it suits you, otherwise feel free to use something else.

What I would do is create an interface (or if the components are almost identical, a super class) like this :

```
export interface ComponentX {
  title: string;
  data: any[];
  headers: string[];
}
```

Now, your components would have to implement that, and they can all use the same template/style :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'comp-A',
  templateUrl: '../component-X.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../component-X.component.scss']
})
export class ComponentA implements ComponentX {
  title = 'Component A';
  data = [];
  headers = ['ID', 'full name', 'phone number'];
}
```

This way, all of your components would be forced to have the properties of your interace, and since the properties will remain the same, you will only need one template/CSS file.

The folder structure would look like this (again, if it was my issue) :

```
ComponentX
|
|- componentX.component.html
|- componentX.component.ts
|- componentX.component.scss
|
|- ComponentA
|  |- componentA.component.ts
|
|- ComponentB
|  |- componentB.component.ts
|
|- ComponentC
   |- componentC.component.ts
```

Comment: Thanks for reply and nice example. Of course there is not one right way, but I needed some examples regarding to the right ways... Your example is quite good, but I also need the folder hierarchy for  component A, B, C and their container component X. Any idea about that? Thanks in advance...